# Persistent naming of root device when booting FreeBSD

Tags: boot, freebsd, root-filesystem

Because devices can be plugged and unplugged frequently, referring to the block device that FreeBSD should use as the root device could easily become unreliable. Is there a way to specify the root device via a filesystem UUID or via a partition UUID as with Linux?

Comment: Use a label for your filesystem.

Comment: @paladin Awesome. How do specify it in the boot arguments? Can a partition (as opposed to filesystem) GUID also be used?

Comment: And a very small nitpick: FreeBSD uses character and [not block devices](https://docs.freebsd.org/en/books/arch-handbook/driverbasics/#driverbasics-block)

Comment: Please give us more details about your current situation and what you want to achieve.

Comment: @paladin I don't have a particular "situation" at the moment. The scenario of a computer that has different storage devices constantly being attached and detached is the hypothetical "situation". If it makes it easier, then assume that FreeBSD is on a USB drive.

Answer (score 2):

It is human nature to ask the way you do. But it requires that people know both Linux and wants FreeBSD to behave in the same way.

A much better approach would be to flesh out what you are specifically trying to do. In this case you can be led down a dark path you probably do not want to go.

Because the direct answer is "yes" and will lead you to [devd](https://man.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=devd&sektion=8) and [devfs](https://man.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=devfs&sektion=8). Both powerful tools and we can play with the UUIDs as you suggest.

It is however most likely that you do not want to do that unless you have very very specific reasons to do so.

FreeBSD have been using the ZFS filesystem for many years. Even as root devices. The ZFS import process identifies the disks and UUIDs automatically. You can swap disks around freely in the system and ZFS handles this gracefully without intervention. If you are using ZFS you should have a look at [Best practice for specifying disks (vdevs) for ZFS pools in 2021?](https://forums.freebsd.org/threads/best-practice-for-specifying-disks-vdevs-for-zfs-pools-in-2021.79161/)

If you choose to use ie. UFS instead then the common approach would be to use disklabels.

To use disklabels you need to use the [GPT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table) partitioning scheme rather than the really old [MBR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record) scheme. This again assumes that we are talking i386 and friends.

You simply use the disklabels in your [fstab(5)](https://man.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=fstab&sektion=5) and you should be familiar with [FreeBSD Handbook: Chapter 20. Storage](https://docs.freebsd.org/en/books/handbook/disks/index.html)

Glabel can be helpful for [finding labels](https://superuser.com/questions/728492/is-there-a-way-tool-to-find-label-to-drive-mappings-in-freebsd) but as stated [here](https://forums.freebsd.org/threads/create-and-use-disk-partition-labels.57086/) should be generally avoided. Use `gpart modify` and `gpart show/list` to change labels - have a look at [gpart(8)](https://man.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?gpart(8))

You can find a quick overview using [FreeBSD Labeled Filesystems](http://www.wonkity.com/%7Ewblock/docs/html/labels.html). But remember what Warren Block wrote in the forum thread above:

> Don't use glabel(8) to write labels to existing filesystems. It will overwrite the last block. In fact, try to avoid using glabel(8) at all.

Or if you have even more specific needs you could look at `/dev/diskid/<id>´, /dev/gpt/<label>`​ or `/dev/gptid/<label>`.

So try to be a little more specific in that you try to accomplish so you avoid Linuxism. Not that Linux is bad but when you expect the same 1:1 behaviour in FreeBSD you might not get the best result.

Comment: I already know about the likes of `/dev/gptid` and the like, but you neglect to mention if those are ways by which the kernel can find the root device when booting.

Comment: Good for you. I profusely apologize for my neglect.

Answer (score 0):

As a concrete example of one aspect of what @ClausAndersen is suggesting, and assuming you're running on the UFS filesystem:

```
# gpart show da0
=>      40  20971440  da0  GPT  (10G)
        40    204800    1  efi  (100M)
    204840   8388608    2  freebsd-swap  (4.0G)
   8593448  12378032    3  freebsd-ufs  (5.9G)
```

First add GPT labels to your partitions:

```
# gpart modify -l uefi-boot -i1 da0
da0p1 modified
# gpart modify -l swap-space -i2 da0
da0p2 modified
# gpart modify -l ufs-root -i3 da0
da0p3 modified
# gpart show -l da0
=>      40  20971440  da0  GPT  (10G)
        40    204800    1  uefi-boot  (100M)
    204840   8388608    2  swap-space  (4.0G)
   8593448  12378032    3  ufs-root  (5.9G)
```

With suitable GPT partition labels in place, simply reference the filesystem partition by its GPT label in `/etc/fstab`:

```
/dev/gpt/ufs-root       /        ufs     rw       0       0
```

If you really are running on a thumb drive, then labels like `thumb-efi` `thumb-swap` and `thumb-ufs` might be apt.  In ZFS installations, best practice is usually to create the partition label based on the serial number of the drive, so that failed drives can be unambiguously identified.